# Selenium click on button

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

On web-page there is button, which describe by code below:

```
<button onclick="getListRating(1); return false;" class="button is-gray pagination__more">Open</button>
```

Need to click by use selenium lib - first i tried to find as "css_celector" but it didn't work:

```
allm=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button is-gray pagination__more')  # Find button
allm.click() # Click!
```

What find class i need to use to click this button?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd find the button by the onclick attr. Here is a solution with xpath.

```py
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@onclick="getListRating(1); return false;"]')
button.click()
```